# Get list of nouns and declension of a word from Wiktionary API

Tags: wikimedia, wiktionary

I would like to get:

1. a list of nouns in a specific language
2. the case declension table for a word in a slavic language.

I was hoping to be able to send something like an http get request with parameters:

```
https://cs.wiktionary.org/wiki/wordlist/nouns
```

And for the declension table I was also hoping for an http request and then a response as a JSON object, eg.:

```
https://cs.wiktionary.org/wiki/program/declension
```

Expected response:

```
{
"word":"program",
"singular_declension":
    [
        "nominative":"program",
        "genitive":"programu",
        "dative":"programu",
        "accusative":"program",
        "vocative":"programe",
        "locative":"programu",
        "instrumental":"programem",
    ]
"plural_declension":
    [
        "nominative":"programy",
        "genitive":"programů",
        "dative":"programům",
        "accusative":"programy",
        "vocative":"programy",
        "locative":"programech",
        "instrumental":"programy",
    ]
}
```

Unfortunately, I cannot find any endpoints for that in the official API specs:
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page
...nor the documentation:
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page

How can I get those results? Or do I have to resort to webscraping and extracting this info from the html pages?

Answer (score 1):

### Action API

Technically, it's possible to use `Action API` in the following manner:

1. find the relevant category (Česká substantiva?)
2. query chunk by chunk all the members of that category ([docs](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Categorymembers#Example_1:_List_twenty_pages_in_a_category), [example](https://cs.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=categorymembers&gcmtitle=Kategorie:Tvary_%C4%8Desk%C3%BDch_substantiv&prop=info&format=json))
3. query parse ([docs](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Parsing_wikitext#API_documentation)) sections for each page ([example](https://cs.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&page=program&prop=sections&disabletoc=1))
4. find by keyword (skloňování?) for declension section
5. query parse ([docs](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Parsing_wikitext#Example_2:_Parse_a_section_of_a_page_and_fetch_its_table_data)) the text of that section ([example](https://cs.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&page=program&prop=text&disabletoc=1&section=6))
6. parse finally the `HTML` containing the desired table.

Yet this way is hardly scalable.

### English Wiktionary

It's hard to claim so, but it seems that English Wiktionary contains most of the lemmas of other languages. `program` in Czech **is** also there and [with declensions](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/program#Declension). Furthermore, section name is a standard across all languages (Declension) also the `HTML` table has lots of metadata inside and is much easier to parse. As an example of a word form:

```html
<span class="Latn form-of lang-lv acc|s-form-of" lang="lv"><a...>māsu</a></span>
```

Yet before implementing parsing, it is usually a good idea to check for existing solutions.

### Wiktextract and Kaikki

These two projects are both based English Wiktionary dumps. [Wiktextract](https://github.com/tatuylonen/wiktextract) provides `cli` and `python` interface for such dumps. [Kaikki](https://kaikki.org/dictionary/) holds the recent extracted version and provides `HTTP` interface to that. Here are few examples:

All Czech nouns (be careful, it's 46,6MB):

```
https://kaikki.org/dictionary/Czech/by-pos-noun/kaikki_dot_org-dictionary-Czech-by-pos-noun.json
```

`program` description:

```
https://kaikki.org/dictionary/Czech/meaning/p/pr/program.json
```

Has slightly different structure from desired, but easily convertible:

```json
...
{"form": "programům", "tags": ["dative", "plural"], "source":  "declension"}, 
{"form": "program", "tags": ["accusative", "singular"], "source": "declension"}
...
```

### Sample code

If the above projects somehow cannot be used, here are some sample parsing code in `python`.

First, we need to somehow detect language sections, and having a lookup dictionary seems to be good option:

```py
import iso639

languages = {}
for line in iso639.data:
    if not line['iso639_1']:
        continue
        
    names = line['name'].split(';')
    for name in names:
        # handle few exceptions:
        # * Interlingua (International Auxiliary Language Association)
        # * Occitan (post 1500)
        # * Tonga (Tonga Islands)
        name, *_ = name.split('(', maxsplit=1)
        name = name.strip()
        languages[name] = line['iso639_1']

# Serbo-Croatian doesn't exist in ISO, but is used in Wikipedia & Wiktionary 
languages['Serbo-Croatian'] = 'sh'
```

Section finder:

```py
def get_section_id(data: dict, keyword: str, language: str):
    
    try:
        sections = data['parse']['sections']
    except (KeyError, TypeError):
        return None
    
    section_language = None
    for section in sections:
        if section['line'] in languages:
            section_language = section['line']
            continue

        if section['line'] == keyword and section_language == language:
            return int(section['index'])
    
    return None
```

Processing:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = f'https://en.wiktionary.org/w/api.php'

word = 'māsa'

params = {
    'action': 'parse',
    'format': 'json',
    'page': word,
    'prop': 'sections',
    'disabletoc': True
}

response = requests.get(url, params=params)

section_id = get_section_id(response.json(), 'Declension', 'Latvian')

params = {
    'action': 'parse',
    'format': 'json',
    'page': word,
    'prop': 'text',
    'section': section_id,
    'disabletoc': True
}

response = requests.get(url, params=params)
# word may not exist, may raise exceptions
html = response.json()['parse']['text']['*']

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
```

Result:

```py
result = {
    "word": word,
    "singular_declension": {
        "nominative": soup.find("span", class_="nom|s-form-of").text,
        "genitive": soup.find("span", class_="gen|s-form-of").text,
        "dative": soup.find("span", class_="dat|s-form-of").text,
        "accusative": soup.find("span", class_="acc|s-form-of").text,
        "vocative": soup.find("span", class_="voc|s-form-of").text,
        "locative": soup.find("span", class_="loc|s-form-of").text,
        "instrumental": soup.find("span", class_="ins|s-form-of").text
    },
    "plural_declension": {
        "nominative": soup.find("span", class_="nom|p-form-of").text,
        "genitive": soup.find("span", class_="gen|p-form-of").text,
        "dative": soup.find("span", class_="dat|p-form-of").text,
        "accusative": soup.find("span", class_="acc|p-form-of").text,
        "vocative": soup.find("span", class_="voc|p-form-of").text,
        "locative": soup.find("span", class_="loc|p-form-of").text,
        "instrumental": soup.find("span", class_="ins|p-form-of").text
    }
}

print(result)
```

```
{'word': 'māsa',
 'singular_declension': {'nominative': 'māsa', 'genitive': 'māsas',
                         'dative': 'māsai', 'accusative': 'māsu',
                         'vocative': 'māsa', 'locative': 'māsā',
                         'instrumental': 'māsu'},
 'plural_declension': {'nominative': 'māsas', 'genitive': 'māsu',
                       'dative': 'māsām', 'accusative': 'māsas',
                       'vocative': 'māsas', 'locative': 'māsās',
                       'instrumental': 'māsām'}}
```